# Parse:usercannotbealteredwithoutsessesionerror

Tags: ios, parse-platform

We just recently pushed an update to the app store and when users launch the app they are experiencing the following bug:

[Error Image http://getgratitude.co/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/error-577x1024.png](http://getgratitude.co/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/error-577x1024.png)

For some reason, the install messed up [PFUser currentUser] ? I haven't changed the parse SDK in either of the last few updates. This bug is happening to every user that updated to the latest version. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you so much.

Comment: Have you traced the error to find out whip bit of code it is? Is it a session related issue so the users aren't logged in anymore?

Comment: It appears to be a session related issue because the users aren't logged in anymore. I haven't been able to find a line of code that is causing the issue. If the user deletes the app and reinstalls, then they are able to login and use the app like normal again.

Comment: There's a switch in the web interface for your app where you can turn off the session stuff, it may help